# In yii how json formatted inputs are inserted into tables

Tags: json, yii, extjs4

I am creating project using extjs and yii. My client side design is in extjs-4 and server side design is in yii framework.

Now I am having table **Poll** with fields as:

- pollid
- pollQuestion
- Isactive
- Userid

And **Polloption**:

- pollid
- option

Now during creation of new pole,poll creation view form which is designed in extjs will receive inputs and will send this data to server side in json format as-

```
{
  'success':true,
  'results':[ {
              'pollid' : 1,
               'pollQuestion' : 'Which is capital of india',
           } 
           {  options from polloption table in json format
   }]
}
```

So at server side all this values will come in json format. So now in yii i want to insert this received inputs in corresponding poll tables fields.

So how Yii will convert this json formatted inputs and also insert those values into repective fields of poll table. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague and general.  Here's an overview of what you'll want to do:

- submit the data to a Yii controller
- If the data is in the body, use PHP's [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).  If you POST or GET it, you can use Yii's [CHttpRequest::getParam](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) to read in the raw JSON
- use [CJSON::decode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#decode-detail) to parse the JSON into a PHP array
- manipulate the array values, and build a new array
- return the data (echo or print it if you just need the raw JSON and don't need a view).  You'll probably want to return JSON again to use it in extjs4, so you'll want to use the [CJSON::encode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON#encode-detail) method

Comment: Thanx sir for reply. But if poassible can you please give me link of documentation from where i can read detail information.